# Why Videoview can't play a Youtube Video?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-videoview

I'm trying to play a Youtube video from Youtube on some devices, but they return a dialog: "The video can't be played".

I've already read the Youtube API Documentation.

I've a VideoView and I set the video Uri as a url with a .3pg extension.

This is my code:

```
 VideoView videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.video); 
 MediaController mc = new MediaController(this); 
 videoView.setMediaController(mc);
 videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://v1.cache2.c.youtube.com/CigLENy73wIaHwmhXrOROaqgpBMYESARFEgGUgx1c2VyX3VwbG9hZHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp")); 
 videoView.requestFocus(); 
 videoView.start();
```

I've tried other videos and play correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Some videos are banned from playing on mobile devices, have you tried to play it on your cell phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If embedding video is not your explicit requirement, Why don't you simply start an intent with the Youtube video URL and let the OS handle the intent for you ? This is the simplest possible way to play video on android as far as I know. 
For example,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("Your youtube URL here"));
startActivity(intent);
```

For more information about Android Intents, see [this link](http://blog.vimviv.com/android/intent-android/) and [vogella's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#intents_explicit)

Comment: What if embedding video is my explicit requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet will hel you.

Basically you will need `setOnPreparedListener`

```
 try {

                final VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
                // Set video link (mp4 format )
                Uri video = Uri.parse(video_url);
                videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                       progressDialog.dismiss();
                       videoView.start();
                    }
                });

             }catch(Exception e){
                 progressDialog.dismiss();
                 System.out.println("Video Play Error :"+e.getMessage());
             }
```

Comment: sorry this is not working for me. i just want to play you tube video into video view but i can't play by this way. can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to launch an intent with a YouTube URL and let the OS handle it. That is, I don't think you can embed YouTube videos directly into your activities though I would love to be proven wrong.